# How can I catch an error caused by mail()?

Tags: php, email

Does anyone know how can I catch a mail error (error is displayed while sending email and the error is caused by the mailserver down) in php?

Error that was caused by emailserver down is below:

> <!--2010-02-24T14:26:43+11:00 NOTICE (5): Unexpected Error: mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "ip " port portip, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() (# 2).
>   2010-02-24 14:26:43
>   Username: admin
>   Error in line 439 of file D:\test.php
>   Script: /customer.php
>    [Global Error Handler]
>   -->

Comment: How do you send mails? Are you talking to the SMTP server directly?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is about the best you can do:

```
if (!mail(...)) {
   // Reschedule for later try or panic appropriately!
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

> `mail()` returns `TRUE` if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, `FALSE` otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

If you need to suppress warnings, you can use:

```
if (!@mail(...))
```

Be careful though about using the [`@`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) operator without appropriate checks as to whether something succeed or not.

---

If `mail()` errors are not suppressible (weird, but can't test it right now), you could:

a) turn off errors temporarily:

```
$errLevel = error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);  // suppress NOTICEs
mail(...);
error_reporting($errLevel);  // restore old error levels
```

b) use a different mailer, as suggested by [fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323463/how-can-i-catch-an-error-caused-by-mail/2324857#2324857) and [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323463/how-can-i-catch-an-error-caused-by-mail/2323558#2323558).

If `mail()` turns out to be too flaky and inflexible, I'd look into b). Turning off errors is making debugging harder and is generally ungood.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Often times people forget that `mail()` returns a `bool`. Good that you referenced the "if no error, the mail arrived" assumption too as this is a common misconception amongst new developers too.

Comment: Hi deceze, I understand that mail() will return true or false. But unknown reason, this is always showing the error message on my page ( which the error message show on my question above and the error only able to view when I view the source code from the page):

and this error caused me unable to redirect (header() )my page to the new page. I have search around the code but unable to find out where actually display this error. Perhaps this is set in the php stmp setting?

Comment: My question is ... how can I ignored or throw this "Failed to connect to mailserver" error message from my page heading? Do anyone have idea how to do it? I been searching around in google but still unable to find out the solution

Comment: Great thank you worked for me. One thing for people to look out for is that you set the headers correctly.

$headers = 'From: ' .$email . "\r\n". 
  'Reply-To: ' . $email. "\r\n" . 
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Answer (score 7):

PHPMailer handles errors nicely, also a good script to use for sending mail via SMTP...

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Actually I think it echoes an error if you didn't set the exception property to true

Comment: I dived into its code and it just uses temporary 'safe mode' + @mail() to handle errors.

Answer (score 5):

also using http://php.net/error_get_last will not help you out, because mail() does not emmit its errors into this function.

Only way seems to be using a proper mailer, like already suggested above.

Comment: This claim seems to have some value, `mail` returns false for me but `error_get_last` is null.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php, use:

```
print_r(error_get_last());
```

Which will return an array of the last error generated. You can access the `[message]` element to display the error.

Comment: its not according to manual, but according to comments in manual, and it really is misleading, and should never use this.  
last error can be deprecation notice somewhere in the code, which will not break the execution, especially in production if set properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/) classes and methods, which allows you to check for errors via:

```
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
```

You can find an example [here](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm).