# php mail notification

Tags: php, forms, email

Ok I'm new to php coding and am working on a form mail php ( a form who's content's are mailed to an email address) the code works fine. Now I'd like to know if there's a way to notify the visitors about the success or failure of the mail. ( dynamically add a line to the form page which mentions "success" or "failure try again". Hope I've been clear enough.

Here's the code

```
    <?php

    $name = $_POST["name"]; 

    $company = $_POST["company"]; 

    $email = $_POST["email"]; 

    $contact =$_POST["contact"]; 

    $require = $_POST["requirement"]; 


    $message = "Name :".$name."\n"."Company  :".$company."\n"."Email id".$email."\n"."Contact no :".$contact."\n"."Requirement : ".$require;

    $subject ="Subject Matter Here";

    $to = "abc@xyz.com";

    if(mail($to, $subject,$message)){
echo "We Received Your enquiry, We'll get back to you soon";
     } 
      else{ 
echo "there were some errors sending enquiry, please try again";
     }




      ?>
```

Comment: How is the form posted? Sent to a different page? AJAX?

Comment: well there's an html file with the form with action set to this script... now i want to dynamically update the html

Comment: Thanks all for your help, I fixed the problem with a little javascript (not exactly what I was looking for but a good compromise)

basically i call a javascript when the php code executes, the script handles the rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$send = mail($to, $subject, $message);

if(!$send){
    echo 'Failed to send!';
}
```

The [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function:

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.

Comment: this will only confirm that the server is not completely misconfigured. There is no practical way to determine if an email reaches the recipient.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I'm aware of that (most people who've used the mail() function on various hosting platforms will know that nothing is ever certain with it). Hence the reason I included the quote from the PHP documentation.

Comment: yes yes I tried this.. problem is after hitting "submit" it goes to a blank page with the text there.. what I want is a line to appear dynamically below the form on the same page itself. Thanks for the help though..

Comment: I've edited the post with the code... hope I'v done it right considering its my first time...

Answer (score 0):

The mail function returns a boolean value indicating success:

```
$result = mail(...)
if ($result) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo 'Failure try again';
}
```

If mail() returns false, you know for sure the e-mail won't be sent. If mail() returns true, your mail server has accepted the e-mail message, but it may still not be delivered. Your mail server tries to send it to another mail server, which may reject the message. You will get a bounce message, but because this does not happen instantly you can not show the result on your form.

If you want to make (more) sure the e-mail is delivered, you have to connect to the destination host yourself. Get the MX record for the domain, connect to the STMP server and send it directly to the destination server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323463/how-can-i-catch-an-error-caused-by-mail) and 
[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

and use it like so:

```
if (!mail(...)) {// Reschedule for later try or panic appropriately!}
```

`mail() returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.`

It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.