# PHP Mail Just works sometimes, others not?

Tags: php, sendmail

So I'm working on a Wordpress installation for a buddy, making a form send to his email address.  I've been testing out the mail function and.. Well, it seems like after a certain number of times I test it, it just stops working...

I've got an

```
if( mail( ... ) )
    echo " =) things are workin out all right...";
else
    echo "fuk...";
```

statement checking to see whether mail is sending.. and after a while it just stops working.

Is there a setting that limits the number of mails that can be set or something?  Am I just sending too much mail?!

Now.. After I wait a while (say a day), mail is suddenly working again.. hm...

Comment: What host are you using? Some hosts limit how many messages can be sent per minute/hour/day.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm really not sure.  I just have FTP access to the Wordpress installation.  I guess that must be it.

Comment: I know that hosts like 000Webhost, Hosting24, HourB, PowrHost (e.g. all hosts that are run by 'Main Hosting') limit the number of messages. They also only let you send 1000 messages in total.

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting?  Looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323463/how-can-i-catch-an-error-caused-by-mail it seems that you should be getting some kind of error thrown.  What does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hosts limit how many messages can be sent per minute/hour/day.

---

To work around this, I set up a second Gmail account to send messages from a script using [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com), then made this script (called `mail.php`):

```
<?php
include_once 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
function do_mail($from, $name, $to, $subject, $message, $debug = false) {
    $blah = base64_decode('base64-encoded password here');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    if($debug) $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = 'username@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = $blah;
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $name);
    $mail->AddAddress($to, $to);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $body = $message;
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->AltBody = $message;
    if($mail->Send()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
?>
```

---

Then, to send a message:

```
<?php
include_once 'mail.php';
$result = do_mail('username@gmail.com', 'First Last', 'someone@example.com', 'Subject here', 'message here');
// Or, with debugging:
$result = do_mail('username@gmail.com', 'First Last', 'someone@example.com', 'Subject here', 'message here', true);
// Print the result
var_dump($result);
?>
```