# Message is missing senders address

Tags: php, sendmail

I am making a contact for a website and I am having issues. 
I am testing with XAMPP currently, using it's sendmail.
I keep getting the error:

> Message is missing sender's address

Here is the PHP Header Code:

```
    //email headers
$headers = 'From: \""' .$email . '\r\n'. 'Reply-To' .
    $email. "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I can't figure out the issue.
Thanks

Comment: `$headers` starts with `From: ""test@example.com`, I don't think this is what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are escaping the double quote in headers, when it does not need to be escaped which will lead to you having two double quotes. Change your code to

```
$headers = 'From: ' .$email . "\r\n". 
  'Reply-To: ' . $email. "\r\n" . 
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: I was following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323463/how-can-i-catch-an-error-caused-by-mail and I needed to add your answer to get it working! Thank you