# PHP contact form not sending e-mail

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have been trying to get a contact form working for my site, and it seems to be. There are no errors as far as I can see, and the success-message is shown when the form is sent, but no e-mail lands in my inbox. I am not very strong in PHP, so can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "myemail@mydomain.dk";

$email_subject = "Itesso ELS kontaktform";





function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "Beklager, men der er et problem med de felter du har udfyldt.";

    echo "Du kan se fejlene markeret nedenfor.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Venligst ret og prøv igen.<br /><br />";

    die();

}



// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

    died('Beklager, men der er et problem med de felter du har udfyldt.');       

}



$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

$error_message .= 'Du har indtastet en ugyldig e-mail.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

$error_message .= 'Du har indtastet et ugyldigt fornavn.<br />';

}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

$error_message .= 'Du har indtastet et ugyldigt efternavn.<br />';

}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

$error_message .= 'Du har indtastet en ugyldig kommentar.<br />';

}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

died($error_message);

}

$email_message = "Detaljer nedenfor.\n\n";



  function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

  }



$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>
```

And here is my html:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

<table width="450px">

<tr>

<td valign="top">

<label for="first_name">First Name *</label>

</td>

<td valign="top">

<input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td valign="top"">

<label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>

</td>

<td valign="top">

<input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td valign="top">

<label for="email">Email Address *</label>

</td>

<td valign="top">

<input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td valign="top">

<label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>

</td>

<td valign="top">

<input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td valign="top">

<label for="comments">Comments *</label>

</td>

<td valign="top">

<textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Comment: please add some code so we can help you out!

Comment: What OS are you running? `Linux`, `Unix`, `Windows`? Have you correctly set up `php.ini` file?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Also add information about the mail service you use to send emails, and if possible check the related logs to see if your mails were refused or anything else.

Comment: When you asking question please upload your code. Then its easy to give solution without telling all the notes. If you upload code we can moderate as working code. Thank You

Comment: Are you trying to send mail from your localhost?

Comment: @D4V1D I am using azure to upload my files through Visual Studio online, so Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Check your coding something like this. This is basic method of sending E-Mail through php.

Example code is below:

```
  //Email information
  $admin_email = "someone@example.com";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
  $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];

  //send email
  mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);

  //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }

  //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
  else  {
?>

 <form method="post">
  Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
  Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
  Message:<br />
  <textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your implementation works if you correct a small error (but I insist you should better use Abdulla's example).

There is a missing "}" for your first if, it is never closed. And if you use the supressor Tag in PHP (@) you will never know if your mail has given you an error. If you want to read more about mail errors: [How can I catch an error caused by mail()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323463/how-can-i-catch-an-error-caused-by-mail)

If it still does not work, I would consider to check your phpinfo(); if mail is set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I added the missing "}" but now when I press the 'Submit' button I am redirected to http://myurl.net/send_form_email.php. Can you tell me why?

Comment: That's because your "action" goes to "send_form_email.php". Is your html in the same file as your php then you can just write action="" (this points to the same file as you are currently in). If you want to redirect to a different page (html and php are splitted) then I would need to know if you are using Win/Mac/Linux?

Comment: I am using Windows, I am working in Microsoft Azure and uploading through Visual Studio Online.

Comment: Ok, and where do you want to land? I will try to give it as a theoretical example. Say we have mail.php (which includes the php + html you mentioned). You first check (as you did) if post data is sent, if not you show the html (you can easily do that by make an if as you did and include the html in the else part). When you then click on the submit (no post is set) and you have action="" (same-page) you will be directed to the page you are currently. Filled in, then the Post-data is set and the php part will work. After your mail(...) you can then give back some echo "Mail has been sent... ".

Comment: I would like the page to run the php in send_form_email.php and then echo "Mail has been sent...". I am sorry, I'm really new to php and as far as I can understand I cannot have the php code in my html file, where my contact form is.

Comment: Depends on your environment you can basically echo everything (html included). I tried to make my point a little bit more clear in a pastebin, it is really easy to have an exit text if you just change your mail-call into a variable with an echo. http://pastebin.com/Y02MfvrD