# php mail error handling when no smtp server

Tags: php, email, server, smtp

I make a php page to send email. I will give this page to multiple users, but I have no control of the server they will use. And some of them should have no SMTP server. So I try to handle this error.

For example, on my own computer, if I deactivate my SMTP server, I receive a "PHP Warning:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at ..." error message.

My code :

```
  try
  {
    $okmail=mail($to,$Subject,$texte,$headers);
  }
  catch (Exception $ex)
  {
    ...
  }
```

But this code doesn't throw an exception, it only write the error message (like an "echo(...)" statement).
I use this code in a xmlhttprequest page and use an xml type response. But the original page receive the error message before the xml text :
PHP Warning:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at ... \n1Email not send

How can I handle this "no SMTP" error ?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323463/how-can-i-catch-an-error-caused-by-mail

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, the following directive will hide the warnings.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Instead of "try/catch" you can use the following approach.

```
set_error_handler("warningHandler", E_USER_WARNING);

// Trigger some warning here for testing purposes only (this is just an example).
trigger_error('This here is the message from some warning ...', E_USER_WARNING);

// If you need DNS Resource Records associated with a hostname.
// $result = dns_get_record($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

// Restores the previous error handler function.
restore_error_handler();

// This is your custom warning handler.
function warningHandler($errno, $errstr) {
    // Do what you want here ...
    echo $errno, ' ::: ', $errstr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, but nothing works :(

I find a solution by cleaning the output buffer by using ob_start(null,0,PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE) and ob_clean() just after the mail() function.

I don't understand why the mail function writes an error into the output buffer